# Eclipse version 1.8.0_92 of the JVM is not suitable

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run eclipse it say "Version 1.8.0.92 of the JVM is not suitable for this product, Version: 11 or greater required".
Even I have java 16 and 14 it not work , I checked that java folder and found that it was the jre version so I go and try to install the new jre and it was 1.8.0_281 but still it not work , I tried to remove the the jre and keep just java 16 or 14 and it didn't work too when I run it it open a large window with so many lines that I can't see the end of it on the screen.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orpeY.png)

Comment: You need to update file `eclipse.ini` which is in the same folder as file `eclipse.exe`. Search Google for _eclipse.ini_ I can't give you a more precise answer because you have not provided enough details. What version of Eclipse did you install? What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM